# Turning on HDMI programmatically doesn't work

Tags: debian, hdmi, screen

I would like to turn on/off the HDMI via SSH.
I use this command to turn off the HDMI:

`sudo tvservice -o` and it works fine, my monitor turns off.

But after that I would like to turn on the monitor with this command:

`sudo tvservice -p` and my monitor turns on (the led on the monitor shows, the monitor is on) but no picture on the monitor; only a blank black screen.

What I should do turn on my monitor properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out how to fix this problem.
After the

`sudo tvservice -p` command, run this:

`sudo chvt 9 && sudo chvt 7`

That works for me!

Comment: Why are both required? or, are both required?  One or the other makes sense to me, but not both.  I'll try to remember to play with this later when I can watch the screen.

Comment: Because you need to change something so you change 9->7.
If you use only the 9, maybe the current state is 9 so you didnt change anything. But Its not sure....

Comment: ahh that makes sense...

Answer (score 4):

For me this worked for turning on the screen:

```
#!/bin/sh
tvservice -p
fbset -depth 8; fbset -depth 16
xrefresh
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that your monitor is not active. It is just recnognized as an output but no *images* are being sent to it.

For this I'd recommend to use `xrandr` for managing outputs. `--auto` flag should be sufficient:

```
xrandr --auto
```

if not, try to play with that such as:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --primary
```

there are good docs [here](http://pkg-xorg.alioth.debian.org/howto/use-xrandr.html) and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr).

Comment: via SSH a get this message: "Can't open display". I think It works but not via ssh

Comment: I guess you'll need to export `DISPLAY` so X will know what display you are talking about. More about it [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/xrandr-from-remote-through-ssh-869084/)

Comment: Yes maybe this solution work but I didnt try it because i find another way, please see my answer below. That worked fine for me without any complication

Answer (score 1):

In current firmware you can to turn the monitor off and on with the folowing:
OFF: `sudo vcgencmd display_power 0`
ON: `sudo vcgencmd display_power 1`

It does not risk changing resolution, and there is no need for fbset, chvt, xrefresh, or restarting your GLES and OMX overlays afterwards
I've tested it on my Raspberry Pi 3