# How to debug video via ssh

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, hdmi, display

I have a Pi 2 model B and only access to an HDMI display, however I have not gotten any video output despite:

- Having successfully booted RetroPie, pidora, NOOBS, and raspbian
- Having tried every combination of `hdmi_safe=1`, `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` and `config_hdmi_boost=4`
- A multitude of HDMI cables

...so at this point I suspect there may be a legitimate hardware issue with the HDMI controller.

---

With some network monitoring I can manage to get the IP of the Pi when it appears on the network, so I can SSH in. I can even `ssh -X` in and get `tuxeyes`, but no `xrandr`. I'm not even sure how to get video device information without `lspci` working.

**Does anyone know how to (via ssh) interact with the video device, or get any other kind of feedback that would provide information on the display system?**

Comment: Try [`sudo tvservice -p`](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22039/turn-on-hdmi-programatically-but-doesnt-turn-on)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if the following also works for *Pi 2 model B* (which is what your question is all about). But this works for my *Pi 3*:

I *CAN* start it without a HDMI-connected monitor attached, then plug it in, switch it on and activate HDMI:

1. Query the output status of HDMI:

   ```
   sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -s
   ```
2. Activate the monitor:

   ```
   sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -p
   ```
3. Monitor may stay black. However, you want it to display something on TTY console number 1, 2,... or 6. Use the `chvt` (*change virtual terminal*) command:

   ```
   sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -p; sudo chvt 1; sudo chvt 2; ...
   ```
4. Monitor black; you want to see the GUI. Again, use `chvt` and switch it to TTY console number 7:

   ```
   sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -p; sudo chvt 7;
   ```
5. Query monitor for supported CEA modes:

   ```
   sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m CEA
   ```
6. Query monitor for supported DMT modes:

   ```
   sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m DMT
   ```
7. Get more detailed info about the monitor:

   ```
   sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -d edid.dat
   sudo /opt/vc/bin/edidparser edid.dat
   ```
8. Switch off the HDMI monitor:

   ```
   sudo vcgencmd display_power 0
   ```
9. Switch on the HDMI monitor:

   ```
   sudo vcgencmd display_power 1
   ```
10. Disable HDMI out:

    ```
    sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -o
    ```
11. Send keystroke to tty1 to wake up monitor:

    ```
    sudo echo -ne "\033[9;0]" >/dev/tty1
    ```

Answer (score 0):

`tvservice -s` will show current status.

There is no `man` page but if you just type `tvservice` it will list the commands.